# How to page DataGridView with huge row number to get better performance

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a table in MySQL with more than 7000 rows and about 20 fields. I want my user be able to select a single row.

I use common code to fill my DataGridView instance named as dataGridView1 with this table. The code is:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

Although this works, but it always cost more than 10 seconds to display the filled dataGridView1. I remember in web GridView control, it pages it's content to get much better performance.

My question is: can I also page DataGridView control to get better performance?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can I also page DataGridView control to get better performance

Yes,  you can. And you should do the paging on server side. You can take a quick look [Datagrid paging](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16303/DataGrid-Paging-C-Windows-Forms) to see what you need to do.

Note: The code in the example is not the best way to do. It is just an example of how it can be done.

Comment: `DataGrid != DataGridView`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, i have clearly mentioned that example i have given is to just give an idea what needs to be done.